# Significant performance differences in JTextPane when text contains linefeed

Tags: java, performance, jtextpane

I wrote a method that writes *hello world!\n* 10000 times in a JTextPane. I recognized a
significant performance drop when using *hello world!* without linefeed.

Example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class JTextPaneTest {
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    Document doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();

    //constructor
    JTextPaneTest() {               
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++) {
            try {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), i+" hello world!", null);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }
        textPane.setDocument(doc);
        createWindow();
    }

    public void createWindow() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame = new JFrame("frame");     
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(textPane), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);         
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("start...");
        float startTime = System.nanoTime();
        new JTextPaneTest();
        float stopTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.println("elapsed time main: "+stopTime/1000000000+ "s");
    }
}
```

what could be the reason for that phenomena? Any ideas?

Comment: http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePerformance.html the last section suggest a way to fix

Answer (score 1):

A StyledDocument has a two-level data structures: paragraphs (newline!) and under that elements. Style attributes are either for paragraphs or elements.

Adding a newline probably means insert a new (empty) paragraph. In every case more happens, than just an Element insert.